# Laravel Passport: как создать access_token + refresh_token + scopes

Tags: php, laravel

Как получить `refresh_token` средствами Laravel Passport?

Вот что хочу: на роут отправляется запрос пользователь + пароль:

- user: `user`
- password: `pa$$word`

на выходе получаем:

- access_token вместе со scopes
- refresh_token

Пользователю не дается право выбирать `scopes`, он просто авторизуется, и `scopes` выбираются согласно бизнес-логики `$scopes = $user->scopes();`. Если упростить, то пользователь авторизовался => ему выдали токен с правами только просмотра новостей `scopes: view-news`, но не редактирования `scopes: edit-news`.

Вот мой текущий код:

```
public function getToken(Request $request)
{
  // пользователь авторизован посредством middleware
  $user = Auth::user();

  $email = $user->email;

  // моя реализация получения области видимости для пользователя
  $scopes = $user->scopes();

  // это из Passport трейта "HasApiTokens"
  $token = $user->createToken(sprintf("%s-%s", $email, now()), $scopes);

  return response()->json([
      "access_token" => $token->accessToken,
// как создать рефреш токен?      
//      "refresh_token" => ...,
      "expires_at" => Carbon::parse(
          $token->token->expires_at
      )->toDateTimeString()
  ])->setStatusCode(201);
}
```

`User::createToken()` создает только access_token, а мне нужен также и refresh_token.

В интернете написано, что в контроллере отправлять запросы на `oauth/token`, но тогда не понятно какие `scopes` будут подключены к пользователю, и как ими управлять.

Другими словами:

- `oauth/token` - не понятно как запрограммировать логику привязки `scopes` к пользователю
- `$user->createToken()` - не создается refresh_token

Как мне поступить?

PS. Если в своем контроллере делать HTTP-запрос на `oauth/token` (через Guzzle) - это не желательно, так как не будут работать автотесты, которые используют in-memory database.

Comment: Используйте стандартные механизмы Паспорта у Laravel для получения токенов, вам не нужно писать свои собственные. Авторизацию по токену тоже нужно использовать встроенную. Зачем вам потребовался токен изначально? Для тестирования вы имперсонируете пользователя через [Passport::actingAs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52556630/how-can-i-authenticate-users-in-phpunit-testing-using-passport)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov как в токене access_token указать scopes согласно моей собственной бизнес логики? То, что в коде выше я беру через `$user->scopes();`. В документации об этом не сказано, либо я плохо искал

Comment: [Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport#token-scopes) предоставляют клиенту возможность запросить определенные действия, которые могут быть даны (или нет) при авторизации и выдаче токена. Сначала определите их, а потом передавайте в запросе аналогично примеру.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, я знаю что такое scopes. Мне нужно прописать scopes в access_token согласно бизнес-логике. Как это сделать?

Comment: Зачем, для чего, каков смысл этого? Scopes не хранятся внутри Laravel привязанные к пользователю, они выступают в роли «врат», проверок на действия. Будет логичнее если после авторизации, когда вы получите токен, вызвать с ним отдельные методы и уже в нём отдавать что вам необходимо (массив scopes или чего-то ещё), чем пытаться изменять существующие механизмы имплементации oauth2.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, `Scopes не хранятся внутри Laravel привязанные к пользователю` - почему вы так думаете? Метод `User::createToken()` вторым параметром принимает scopes. `Будет логичнее если после авторизации, когда вы получите токен, вызвать с ним отдельные методы и уже в нём отдавать что вам необходимо, чем пытаться изменять существующие механизмы.` - не понял суть вашей мысли. Я проектирую микросервис, scopes и правила назначения пользователям хранятся только в нем и нигде иначе. Пользователь НЕ выбирает scopes, они прописаны в бизнес-политиках

Comment: Смотрите пример на англоязычном [SO #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50727491/call-accesstokencontroller-issuetoken-directly-from-code), [SO #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45851673/laravel-passport-password-grant-refresh-token) надеюсь поможет.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, спасибо, очень похоже на то, что я ищу.